# Finding tangent line of $f(x) = 1/x$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Find the equation of the tangent line to $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{x}$ through the point $(0, \alpha)$.

Answer: $y = −\alpha^2\dfrac{x}{4} + \alpha$

I've found $f'(x)=-\dfrac{1}{x^2}$ but how do I find $f'(0)$ without getting $-\infty$? Can someone show me the steps they took to arrive at the answer?

Comment: You don't have to find $f'(0)$, you seek to find a tangent line to the given curve which PASSES through $(0,\alpha)$.

Comment: The point $(0,\alpha)$ is clearly not on the curve.

Comment: The trick here is to find which point on the curve has a tangent line that passes through the given point. As you move along the curve (in the first quadrant) from right to left, the tangent line sweeps out all of the upper half-plane that lies below or to the left of the curve, so such a point must exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider any point $\left(h,\dfrac{1}{h}\right)$ on the curve.

The equation of tangent at this point is:
$$y-\frac{1}{h}=f'(h)\left(x-h\right) \Rightarrow y-\frac{1}{h}=\frac{-1}{h^2}\left(x-h\right)\Rightarrow y=-\frac{x}{h^2}+\frac{2}{h}$$
Since the tangent passes through $(0,\alpha)$,
$$\alpha=\frac{2}{h}\Rightarrow h=\frac{2}{\alpha}$$
Substituting back this value of $h$, the equation of tangent is:
$$y=-\frac{\alpha^2}{4}x+\alpha$$
$\blacksquare$